# How mature is PHP:SVN

Tags: php, svn

I was thinking about using [PHP:SVN](http://uk.php.net/svn) for managing svn repositories on a production website. Currently svn commands are built up and executed on the command line which feels like a major security vulnerability.

PHP:SVN would have the advantage of not executing any commands directly and allowing me to scrap a lot of code.

My question is how mature is the module and is it usable on a production site? Most of the pages about it bear the warning "This function is EXPERIMENTAL and may change". But this would only matter if upgrading the version of PHP.

Comment: +1 ineresting to know, but had no time to take a look...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original PECL package is [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/svn), it should give you some feel on how mature it is. And [here](http://pecl.php.net/bugs/search.php?cmd=display&status=Open&package_name[]=svn) is a list of the current open bugs for this package.

Answer (score 2):

*experimental* should be taken with a grain of salt. There are several PHP extensions that are marked as such, which are quite stable. That said, I don't know what the state of this particular package is.

You might want to write a wrapper, so that you can switch between using your current approach and using the extension.